# Is the execution of inline javascript in a link granted?

Tags: javascript, html

When I use something like `<a href="index.html" onclick="function">Link</a>` - is the execution of the function granted or does the loading of `index.html` interfere with this?

Comment: It is granted, but usually useless.

Comment: window.replace() does not work in a firefox extension and this is the reason I need to use the link instead.

Comment: May be you could provide more details of  the actual problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: It is a language select menu (of an extension), that sets a storage item of the extension. When the user clicks on a certain language, a message is sent to the extension that stores the value of the selected language and then he is redirected to a content page in the right directory (which is dependant on the selected language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click events are handled before the link is followed, but if they perform any asynchronous activity (e.g. using `XMLHttpRequest` or `setTimeout`) then the page may unload before the activity is finished. If the JS attempts to navigate (e.g. by setting `location` to a new value) then that will usually be overridden by the browser following the link.

Answer (score 1):

Your function will be executed before `index.html` is loaded. This is because you can return `false` (or call `event.preventDefault()`) from your function to prevent the browser from navigating to `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

The `function` will executed before, usually you could use a `function` in order to cancel the default event, see following please:

```js
function test(){
  var canIgo = document.getElementById("chkEnabled").checked;
  console.log("Go to bottom is allowed? " + canIgo);
  if(!canIgo){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="test" href="#end" onclick="javascript:test()">Go to bottom</a>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkEnabled">Allow to go to bottom
<p>Very long test</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse orci augue, ornare et sem ac, imperdiet tincidunt tortor. Ut sit amet nisl pharetra, feugiat nunc nec, sodales dui. Praesent sit amet nisl efficitur, venenatis urna in, varius mauris. Nam in erat laoreet, vulputate metus a, malesuada quam. Nunc a tellus nec justo molestie venenatis sed ut est. Pellentesque porta feugiat sem, et facilisis risus feugiat sit amet. Suspendisse eu blandit nisi. Fusce vitae dolor est.
</p>
<p>
Mauris ullamcorper, lacus a commodo gravida, est magna consectetur nisi, in ultrices nunc justo a lorem. Sed at scelerisque nibh, ac vulputate eros. Etiam scelerisque tristique ligula, sit amet porta nibh pharetra sed. Aliquam eu nisl nec urna sagittis dignissim eget eu nunc. Aenean rutrum nisl velit, vitae hendrerit metus consectetur in. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla sagittis nibh mauris, et maximus urna gravida non. Ut sit amet consectetur nibh. Suspendisse a lobortis dolor. Integer gravida mollis interdum. Integer condimentum lacus malesuada dignissim mattis. Ut fermentum dictum pretium. Proin vulputate fringilla ex, non pellentesque sem blandit at. Pellentesque in velit a sem luctus placerat. Quisque vehicula vitae arcu id pretium.
</p>
<span id="end">END</span>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.